# Conversion of yolov7.pt file into .onnx file format (is Reparameterization needed)

Tags: opencv, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime, yolov7

A .pt model file which is directly converted into .onnx format and a .pt model file first reparameterized and then converted into .onnx format what is the difference between these two file after conversion.

can i read the .pt file using c++ API with any other way?